# Dequeueing cells from UITableView that have xib files enabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uikit

In my UITableViewController subclass, I register my cell class as follows:

`[[self fieldListTableView] registerClass:[MyCellClass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];`

I then dequeue the cell using the method introduced in iOS 6:

`MyCellClass* cell = (MyCellClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

However the cell's xib file seems to be missing. When I run `po cell` in lldb, I get a valid looking cell object. Then when I try `po [cell myLabelOutlet]`, I get a `nil` in response.

Do I need to register the XIB file too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To load cells from a xib file, you have to register it with `registerNib:`, not with
`registerClass:`. Example:

```
[self.fieldListTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCellClass" bundle:nil]
  forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];
```

Comment: When I do this, I get a SIGABRT on this line: `MyCellClass* cell = (MyCellClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Comment: This answer is right. I was doing something wrong in the XIB file as well, which is what caused the crash.